# $\mathbb{R}$ with finite complement topology

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{R}$ with finite complement topology path connected or not ? Hope everyone help out for this question

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230444/is-a-set-with-the-cofinite-topology-path-wise-connected)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner But $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable

Comment: the discussion I linked to is not restricted to countable sets