# What are the continuous maps from [0,1] with usual topology to N with co finite topology??

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If image of such continuous function is infinite then I can't actually construct such map..and also I can't exactly claim that this map is constant..

Comment: The image has to be compact, since $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$ is a compact interval. So, now the question it what are all the compact sets in $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology?

Comment: What kind of characterization of the functions are you looking for? I would say that, since a function is continuous iff the preimage of any cofinite set is open, then it's all the functions such that the preimage of any point is closed.

Comment: See also: [Proving function between topological spaces must be constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2272227) and [Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ with cofinite topology is not path-connected space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/743061)

Comment: A theorem by Sierpiński says that a compact connected Hausdorff space (aka a continuum) cannot be a union of countably many pairwise disjoint and non-empty closed sets (unless there is only one set $X$ in that family). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6338/4280).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be continuous, then $f^{-1}(a)$ is closed for every $a\in\mathbb N$. On the other hand, if this condition holds, then the inverse image of any finite subset will be a finite union of closed and hence also closed, which proves $f$ is continuous. Hence such a map is equivalent to decompose $[0, 1]$ to a disjoint union of closed subsets.

Such a decomposition has to be trivial by this question: [Is $[0,1]$ a countable disjoint union of closed sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/is-0-1-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-sets)

Therefore the only continuous maps from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb N$ are constants.